# How to set QDialog not visible on exec() method?

Tags: c++, qt, invisible, qdialog

i start QDialog with exec() method , now i like it to invisible until some inner object inside it (Qwebkit ) will finish its stuff.
in the QDialog constructor i set it to :

```
setVisible(false);
hide()
```

but will when i do where pAuthenticationDialogContainer is pointer to QDialog :

```
if(pAuthenticationDialogContainer->exec() != QDialog::Accepted ) { ....}
```

i can see the QDialog for few seconds (1-2 seconds )
how can i make it fully invisible ?
Thanks

Comment: You have QWebView in your dialog and you want to show the dialog when loadFinished signal is emitted, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered connecting the button the user presses with `close()` or `accept()` slots from QDialog?

```
connect(pAuthenticationDialogContainer->loginButton,
        SIGNAL(clicked()),
        pAuthinticationDialogContainer,
        SLOT(accept()));
```

Which supposed to hide the dialog.  You will have to make this code exact and test it but this should do this automatically for you.  Beyond that I think posting code for the `else` clause of the condition would be helpful.